# Spark Scala - Extract elements of an array into new row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a following piece of code, where I see the result, but do not understand how exactly it is made:

```
val Df = Seq(Seq(4,7,9)).toDf("x")
val Ds = Df.withColumn("t", $"x").as[(Seq[Int], Seq[Int])]
ds.flatMap{
case(x1,x2) => x2.map((x1,_))
}.toDf("v1","v2")
```

Result looks like this:

```
+---------+---+
|v1       |v2 |
+---------+---+
|[4, 7, 9]|4  |
|[4, 7, 9]|7  |
|[4, 7, 9]|9  |
+---------+---+
```

My questions are:
1) How come this:

```
Df.withColumn("t", $"x").as[(Seq[Int], Seq[Int])]
```

enters same content to both columns, even though this specific Seq does not have a name to refer to? Why doesn't it create empty sequences?

2) result of the flatmap should be list/array, why it becomes a dataset with 2 columns?

3) what does mean `case (x1,x2)` in this particular situation? Why is it in brackets?

4) `x2.map((x1,_))` which exactly operations does map function perform here? I see, that it takes x2 (second column), I understand that "_" means an element of a Seq, but I totally miss the whole coherent picture.

Answer (score 0):

1) `t`has the same content as `x`, so have a a dataframe with two columns (`x`,`t`), both array-type with same contents

2) `map` in DataFrame API maps over rows, not over the element of one row. `x2.map((x1,_))` becomes a `Seq` of tuples, the first being `x1` (i.e. your `x` column), the second is one element of your `t` column array

3) this is pattern-matching (`unapply`) on a tuple2 (i.e. `Seq[Int], Seq[Int])`), `x1` und `x2` are both Seqs/arrays

4) this is the same as `select($"x",explode($"t"))` in DataFrame API. For every element in `t`, a new row is created (thus you get 3 rows)

Comment: 1) but WHY t column has same content as x column? Is it because there is only one column is DF? So what would happen, if there would more than one columns?

Comment: @EstherMallow because `.withColumn("t",$"x")` is just doing that, it's copying the column `x` to a new column named `t`. What else did you expect?

Comment: 2) If 'map' runs over rows, but x1/x2 are tuples, where are the rows here?

Comment: @EstherMallow x1/x2 are NOT tuples, (x1,x2) is a tuple... so x1 and x2 are the elements of the tuple (i.e. `Seq[Int]`)

Comment: 4) Yes, I understand the result of the function, but I don't understand how it works, the logic.  `map` function goes through each element of `x2` and  - does what? Returns whole `x1` Seq and element of `x1`? But why it takes each time new element? Why doesn't it return, for example, only first element of Seq?

Comment: @EstherMallow sorry, I cannot explain you the entire Scala language, but there are plenty of textbooks out there